# Custom Form Field Naming Within Loop

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to specify field names within a loop on a form, so that the fields do not overwrite themselves. Right now I'm using this in my form:

```
class TicketForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        exclude = ['products']

class ProductForm(forms.Form):
    product_id = forms.IntegerField()
    count = forms.IntegerField()

class TicketProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        exclude = []
    for Product in Product.objects.all():
        product_id = forms.IntegerField(initial=Product.product_id)
        count = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
```

The for loop within TicketProductForm currently only displays one set of fields, as product_id and count overwrite the fields over and over, only displaying for the last entry in the set of Product.

Is there a way to customize field names so that I can name them, preferably with a way I can set a specifier to allow easier lookup later?

Comment: Please explain your question clearly. What do you want to do with all product ids?

Comment: I want to create form fields for each product, one with a product_id that contains the current products id, and the other a field where I can input a count. I want to name the field something like 'product_id_xxxx' where xxxx is the products id.

Comment: As far as I am getting your point, You want to display all the product's forms (seperate for each product) on a html page and edit them. Is that what you want then I can help you.